# How to subtract buy/sell rows for each group in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| symbol | side | min | max | mean | wav |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000038 | buy | 0.931 | 1.0162 | 0.977 | 0.992 |
| 1000038 | sell | 0.932 | 1.0173 | 0.978 | 0.995 |
| 1000039 | buy | 0.881 | 1.00 | 0.99 | 0.995 |
| 1000039 | sell | 0.885 | 1.025 | 0.995 | 1.001 |

What is the most pythonic (efficient) way of generating a new dataframe consisting of the differences between the buys and the sells of each symbol.

For example: symbol 1000038, the difference between the and min sell and min buy is (0.932 - 0.931) = 0.001.

I am seeking a method that avoids looping through the dataframe rows as I believe this would be inefficient. Instead looking for a *grouping* type of solution.

I have tried something like this:

```
df1 = stats[['symbol','side']].join(stats[['mean','wav']].diff(-1))
df2 = df1[df1['side']=='sell']
print(df2)
```

but it does not seem to work as expected.

Comment: kindly add your expected output dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You could use the pandas MultiIndex.  First, set up the data:

```
import pandas as pd

columns = ('symbol', 'side', 'min', 'max', 'mean', 'wav')
data = [
    (1000038,  'buy', 0.931, 1.0162, 0.977, 0.992),
    (1000038, 'sell', 0.932, 1.0173, 0.978, 0.995),
    (1000039,  'buy', 0.881, 1.00,   0.99,  0.995),
    (1000039, 'sell', 0.885, 1.025,  0.995, 1.001),
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = columns)
```

Then, create the index and compute the difference between two data frames:

```
df2 = df.set_index(['side', 'symbol'], verify_integrity=True)
df2 = df2.sort_index()

df2.loc[('buy',), :] - df2.loc[('sell',), :]
```

The result is:

```
           min     max   mean    wav
symbol                              
1000038 -0.001 -0.0011 -0.001 -0.003
1000039 -0.004 -0.0250 -0.005 -0.006
```

I'm assuming that each symbol (like 1000038) appears twice.  You could use `fillna()` if you have un-matched buys and sells.

Comment: this is quite elegant,  could one remove cases where the symbol does not occur twice ?

Comment: `dropna()` will remove an un-matched Symbol; just change the last line to: `(df2.loc[('buy',), :] - df2.loc[('sell',), :]).dropna(axis=0, how='all')`